# Multiple querying on Firebase / Firestore

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Dear Firebase Enthusiasts,

I'm having a problem of multiple querying on Firestore. 
*I'm developing for iOS.*

Here's the data structure I'd like to query on:

```
Collection X
    - Document A
      - date: 1532271987 (timestamp)
      - users: { 
                 - user_id_1: "true"
                 - user_id_2: "true"
                 - user_id_3: "true"
                 - ...
               }

    - Document B
      - date: ...
      - users: { 
                 - ...
               }

    - Documents...
```

I'd like to query documents that:

Contains a `user_id_x` on its `users` dictionary
(sth like `users/user_id_x == true`)

`AND`

It's `date` is greater than `SOME_TIMESTAMP`

Which is basically multiple querying on the same API request.

Also I would like to order by date and limit the number of fetched items to enable pagination, but that is sth I can already manage seamlessly, like this:

*Given that I know the `size` of items I'd like to fetch, and a `fromDate` timestamp parameter*

```
collectionReference
              .order(by: "date", descending: false)
              .whereField("date", isGreaterThan: fromDate)
              .limit(to: size)
```

This works pretty fine.

What doesn't work is that I can't have this to be filtered by a `user_id_x` parameter on the server side. So I can't just simply use the following:

```
collectionReference
                  .order(by: "date", descending: false)
                  .whereField("date", isGreaterThan: fromDate)
                  .whereField("users/user_id_x", isEqualTo: true)
                  .limit(to: size)
```

**What I tried before:**

1-

The way of accessing user_id_x on such data structure by using `users/user_id_x` using the `/` should work according to the docs, but I couldn't simply have it work.. (using `users.user_id_x` where using the `.` to access a level deeper simply crashes on SWIFT)

So well, the structure of users doesn't have to be like this.. It can be an array (which I know is not so much preferred for querying.. Or the object can directly be like this:

```
- Document A
          - date: 1532271987 (timestamp)
          - user_id_1: "true"
          - user_id_2: "true"
          - user_id_3: "true"
          - ...
```

However in this case Firestore must create individual indexes for each `user_id_x` present, which doesn't also work for multiple querying by the way.

2-

I tried creating joined indexes (the idea behind libraries like Querybase), where for example:

```
- Document A
          - date: 1532271987 (timestamp)
          - users: { 
                     - user_id_1: "true"
                     - user_id_2: "true"
                     - user_id_3: "true"
                     - ...
                   }
          - date_user_id_1:"true_1532271987"
          - date_user_id_2:"true_1532271987"
          - ...
          - date_user_id_x:"true_SOME_TIMESTAMP"
```

So this structure would allow me to query for something like:

```
....whereField("date_user_id_x", isEqualTo: true_SOME_TIMESTAMP)
```

But this would fetch items that are matching a date.. In order to query for sth like

```
....whereField("date_user_id_x", isGreaterThan: true_SOME_TIMESTAMP)
```

which queries for `isGreaterThan`... Firestore complains (on console) that it must create indexes called `date_user_id_x` on each document.. This has to be done on each and everytime a user becomes related with a timestamp.. I'm not sure how to automate that but it would be too much indexing job either.. Most importantly, 
I'm pretty lost of how to make this work in the exact way I'd like it to be.

3-

**Client Side filtering**

is something I'm trying to avoid..

So the idea behind is, let's pull 10 items from the global dictionary, and then filter them on the device locally, e.g filter if the item has `user_id_x: true`. But this is simply impractical for a social media app like I'm working on, where hundreds and hundreds of users will be present..

I'm trying to avoid it since it would result with using client's network aggressively, and might (most likely) result in fetches with no items relating to the specific user we want to filter to (so I'd have to build a mechanism that would query one more time, and one more until it pulls an X amount of items, which is practically too hard to manage). Moreover I'll be fetching image data based on the results so any mistakes here can result in too much data consumption for the user.

4-
**Creating another dictionary/object to divide this job in multiple queries**

So I can actually create another dictionary that can divide the query work load.. I can first filter on that by users and then with dates, and then pull `Document_X`'s using the fetch results from that dictionary. But this is too hard to manage since there are almost 30+ jobs and cases on my app that results with changes on `Document_X`, `user_id_X` and `some_date` relationships. Maintaining these in a single dictionary is fine.. But to manage them in two dictionaries would simply require me writing 30+ Google Cloud Functions, which would simply mimic changes on 1st dictionary to the other one. Which is not practical at all. I've been down that road and gave up after my 3rd compensating function, since at I quickly filled my data usage quota on Firebase (luckily I was on trial).

**Additional notes:**

I've checked some other SO posts, which basically addresses the few solutions I mention above. I also delved into Google Forums and learned Google has been working on this since 2015, but no results yet.

I think there should be a clever way to do this, easily.. I would very much appreciate your comments, thoughts and guidance on here.

Comment: There's a bit much information in your question, but if I understand correctly this snippet doesn't work: `collectionReference
                  .order(by: "date", descending: false)
                  .whereField("date", isGreaterThan: fromDate)
                  .whereField("users/user_id_x", isEqualTo: true)
                  .limit(to: size)`. What doesn't work about it? Is there an error message (and if so: what error is it)? Or does it give the wrong results (and if so: what's wrong about the results)?

Comment: You're right. I'd like to be able to do two queries towards an object structured like this:
```collection { document { date: 1532271987.240483, description: "Test Description", feeds { 6ROGHv3jMFQlPBUQCwf1sAvyYEJ2: true, AJHYEOOxOJWAoikMOyED9L8BiSb2: true }}}```
To query this, I'm trying..:
```collectionReference.order(by: "date", descending: false).whereField("date", isGreaterThan: fromDate).whereField("feeds/\(userId)", isEqualTo: true).limit(to: size)```
It gives me this error: `Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=9 "The query requires an index. You can create it here: LINK..`

Comment: When I click on the LINK, it opens up the FB console, offers this index:
`feeds.AJH...8BiSb2`  `ASC`
`date` `ASC`

When I create this,
1) the request now doesn't prints this error on the console. But no items are fetched, the request returns no items data.
2) it creates an index dedicated specifically towards the `userId`: `AJH...Sb2` 
3) it's manually done by copying and pasting that link onto a browser
4) takes a while to index.. 

Clearly this flow wasn't intended for such use. I might be constructing that `feeds/\(userId)` part wrongly as well. What would you recommend?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I would sincerely appreciate your help on this. Please let me know if I can provide any other useful information.